# Reducing number of tick labels in matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have an axis date range comprised of datetime objects. But I would just like to display the first and last

```
EODdates = [datetime(), datetime()...]
values = [1.0, 2.0, ...]
data3 = pd.DataFrame(values, EODdates, columns=columns)
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data3, linewidth=2.5, ax=axes[0, 2], legend=False)
```

So ideally just display the year of the datetime object at the start and end of the sequence. So something like `2001` to `2019`.

Comment: I just want this to be on the plot. I.e. no intermediary points.

Comment: I want many points plotted, but I only want a label for the left point (min) and right most point (max). So I want to plot N points, but only 2 labels.

Comment: `plt.xticks([EODdates[0], EODdates[1]])`?